# Highcharts - Not showing data

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

I am trying to find All the values are stored in prodFamilyRunArray. The x-axis labels are stored in xAxis labels. When I tried to hardcode the values inside series and print then it is working. I have attached the screenshot for further reference.

In short it is not being able to take an array reference

```js
var xAxisLabels = [];
var prodFamilyRunArray = [];
var mapOfProdFamilyNames = new Map();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetProductFamilyName", "Automation")',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: '',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            prodFamilyRunArray.push(5);
            xAxisLabels.push(data[i].prodFamily);
            mapOfProdFamilyNames.set(xAxisLabels[i], i);
        }
    }
});

//getProductFamilyExecutionData

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("getProductFamilyExecutionData", "Automation")',
    contentType: "application/json",
    //data:'',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var ind = mapOfProdFamilyNames.get(data[i].prodFamily);
            prodFamilyRunArray[i] = data[i].cnt; // make i to ind here
        }
        //reload
        // $('#container').highcharts().redraw();
        //  setInterval('location.reload()', 50);



    }
});
console.log(xAxisLabels);
console.log(prodFamilyRunArray);
console.log(mapOfProdFamilyNames)

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    //y = Math.random();
                    //series.setData([y]);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Manual vs Automated Executions'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: xAxisLabels
    },

    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Executions'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                'xyx' + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>';
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    if (this.y > 0)
                        return this.y;
                }
            },
            borderWidth: 0,

            maxPointWidth: 40,
            /*events: {
                load: function () {
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        y = Math.random();
                        series.setData([y]);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },

            events: {
                load: function () {
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        y = Math.random();
                        series.setData([y]);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },*/
            /* events: {
                 click: function (event) {
                     //console.log(event);
                     //console.log(event.point.series.name)
                     //console.log(event.point.category.name)



                 }
             },*/

        }
    },



    colors: ['#18a689', '#dd8e07', '#5cbae5', '#930a0a', '#156489', '#2a6d3c', '#f33334', '#71c989', '#3fa45b'],
    series: [{
        name: 'Manual',
        data: prodFamilyRunArray

    }]
});
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting the data correctly? try printing the `data` inside the `success` function

Comment: Yes, I am getting the data correctly @MahbubMoon

Comment: Can you post the actual output of the `prodFamilyRunArray` array?

Comment: This looks like a problem with data processing, but if you have problems with the chart please let me know.